# keep variable value outside the loop

Tags: excel, lifetime

I assign variable value within a loop that is within if statement. When the if statement is exit, variable value becomes unassigned. I need to keep the variable value because I need the updated value in the next iteration.

In the example below, I start with Z=2, then enter the loop, the first IF statement in the loop checks that Z=2 then does the job then reassigns Z=1 then exits the statement, and when the next i-loop iteraction starts, the value of Z is no longer 1 but agains becomes 2. How can I keep the value for the next i-iteration?

```
Sub qwer()

Z = 2

For i = 2 To 80

    If Z = 2 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 2 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A").Value = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "C").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    End If
Exit For

    If Z = 1 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 1 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A") = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "A").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: I have excel file. Column E contains the unique strings, but they fall into 5 classes. Column A says which type the string belongs to (from 1 to 5). Column C says type the next string should be. The strings in Column E should be re-sorted according to this rule in column F.

Comment: 1 22 2  1_6_13_20_22_av_2.wav
2 25 1  2_7_14_19_25_av_1.wav
4 24 5  4_9_14_19_24_av_5.wav
1 21 1  1_8_13_20_21_av_1.wav
3 21 1  3_10_11_16_21_av_1.wav
4 25 2  4_9_14_19_25_av_2.wav
4 22 4  4_9_14_20_22_av_4.wav
1 22 2  1_8_15_17_22_av_2.wav
4 24 5  4_9_15_17_24_av_5.wav
1 21 1  1_6_11_16_21_av_1.wav
This is the spreadsheet.

Comment: The first line of code reads C2 valie (which is 2), assigns it to Z, and then searchers for the first cell in A column with the value of 2, copies the string from E to F and deletes A cell so that it is not read again. And also reads the value in C to check in the next iteration. I cannot thus create different variable, I need to keep the value of Z after I leave the if statement

Answer (score 0):

before Sub qwer() write:

```
Public z As Long
```

That will keep the value while you running your code.
If you stop the code im recommend to save into a VeryHidden sheet.

I hope thiw works for you!

Comment: I have just tried to declare Z as public and it did not work.

Comment: I used the toggles to notice what happens. within the if statement, Z is correctly assigned a new value "1". When it exits the if statement and enters the new i-loop iteration, it gets back its old value "2".

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub qwer()
Z = 2
For i = 2 To 800
    If Z = 2 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 2 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A").Value = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "C").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    ElseIf Z = 1 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 1 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A") = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "C").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    ElseIf Z = 3 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 3 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A") = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "C").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    ElseIf Z = 4 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 4 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A") = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "C").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    ElseIf Z = 5 Then
        For l = 2 To 80
        If Cells(l, "A").Value = 5 Then
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(l, "E").Value
        Cells(l, "A") = ""
        Z = Cells(l, "C").Value
        Exit For
        End If
        Next
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```